# How to capture login hours upon logout in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, time

I am making an application with Laravel 5 and I should have a module to save and update the login hours of a user.

I'm new to programming so I'm going nuts to the logic to how to do it.

This is for call center agents, Their shift is between `3pm to 6am` So for example they login with a timestamp of `2015-07-21 03:00:00` that's `3pm` then if they logout at `4pm` they have `1.0` of login hours then they login again at `7pm` and log out at `5am of 2015-07-21` then that will be their previous login hour which is `1.0` + `10.0` because of `7pm 2015-07-20 - 5am 2015-07-21`. And should update the loginhours of that user.

How can I do this? So now I have a table in my database which is

```
logihours
 ->id
 ->user_id
 ->loginhours (double/float)
 ->timestamp (timestamp of last login/logout)
 ->status (if currently logged in or logged out
```

That is I have now, for sure do this I need to always check in my `login` and `logout` functions but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you using the `Auth` system in Laravel, or do you mean login/logout as a button in your app? Either way you need to capture a timestamp and take an action based on whether it is a login or a logout. Can we see your form/controller or whatever you have at present? It is rather broad currently.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I will use the Login and Logout button of my app to check the user who's logging in or loggin out then also check or update their login hours based on the rules that I mentioned above. As of now I'm not starting to code anything.

Comment: Alright, well assuming those buttons are in a `post` form, create a post route for the form's action in your `routes.php` and point it to a new controller (either one route each, or one route for both). Then in the controller decide if it's a login or logout and take an action accordingly. You may wish to modify your database to explicitly record a login time, even though there is no `loginhours` calculation possible yet. You can then search for this record using Eloquent when you log out.

Comment: You'll need to create models as well. As I say, I wonder if your table structure could do with a bit of adjustment - I'd add login and logout times in the same row, so that a number of hours can be calculated easily. Since it is trivially derivable I wouldn't store it, either.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the advise. I already have a controller and function on where to place the checking which is in  AuthController within postLogin() and getLogout(). What I don't know is how can I calculate the login hours based on their sihft of 3pm to 6am

Comment: Maybe [`DateTime::diff()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)?

Answer (score 2):

create table like that

```
entrance_logs
 ->id
 ->user_id
 ->loged_in_at [default=null]
 ->loged_out_at [default=null]

login_hours
 ->id
 ->user_id
 ->hours [default=0]
```

when user logs in You insert into entrance_logs and define only loged_in_at, when user logs out get last record for this user_id and define only loged_out_at.
then somewhere in controller calculate hours and update login_hours, or create Command in Laravel and shedule it with cron.

for example:

in login action:

```
$EntranceLog = new EntranceLog();
$EntranceLog->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$EntranceLog->loged_in_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$EntranceLog->save();
```

in logout action:

```
$EntranceLog = EntranceLog::where('loged_in_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-86400))
                          ->whereNull('loged_out_at')
                          ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                          ->orderBy('loged_in_at', 'desc')->first();
if($EntranceLog) {
  $EntranceLog->loged_out_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $EntranceLog->save();

  $hours = strtotime($EntranceLog->loged_out_at) - strtotime($EntranceLog->loged_in_at);
  $hours/= 3600;
  $hours = (double)$hours;

  $LoginHour = LoginHour::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
  if(!$LoginHour) {
    $LoginHour = new LoginHour();
    $LoginHour->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
  }
  $LoginHour->hours = (double)$LoginHour->hours + $hours;
  $LoginHour->save();
}
```

and calculate time difference:

Comment: Wow. This is very helpful. Thank you so much. I will try this approach. Thanks for the effort and help :)

Comment: What happens if the user's session expires before they click the logout button?

Comment: That was my answer to question. But must agree that bugs are everywhere. Nobody can guarantee this kind of situation. To avoid this kind of problem better keep "remember" variable in cookie that will hold encrypted data that contains necessary data to recover when garbage collector cleans up session data. Also best approach to keep session encrypted data in cookie (change session driver to cookie). Or need to write special logic that will compare login time with last activity operation and do necessary work.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to tackle this issue, I would store a timestamp in the database called `last_login` that stored the last time the user successfully logged in.

Then on logout, you can compare the current timestamp to the timestamp stored in the database to work out how long they have been logged in.

**Warning:** Another potential issue is the fact that the same user could have multiple sessions (maybe they login on their desktop and their phone?).

Comment: I already made this and this was my logic. It's ok if I will follow a work shift within only the same day. When they logout I can query the user's last login timestamp and compare it to the new login timestamp but my problem now is the work shift doesn't happen within the same day it is now 3pm of the current day to 6am tomorrow. How can I structure it properly?

Comment: Another problem is the fact that sessions timeout before they click the logout button